# ReactJS - getting data from DB and returning promise results from .then back to return function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

**TLDR;** Basically I'm trying to figure out how to get data from my api into my React app on load so my app has it available right away.  I'm totally fine with redoing or reworking any or all of my code below if need be.  I just need to figure out how to do this.  I think it needs to go into the context so that all my components have access to it.

I have created a ReactJS app with hard-coded dummy data and it works great.  Now we need to convert it to pulling in real dynamic data from the database and am having trouble with understanding how promises work with state and useEffect.  It gets so confusing.  I am creating the contextValue object in my final `.then` call and I need that at the end of my file in the `return`.  I tried saving it to a state variable, but that doesn't seem to be working.  I am getting an error `TypeError: _useContext is null` in a different file.

Here is the entire context file with any irrelevant code redacted:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const ScheduleContext = createContext();

export const ScheduleProvider2 = (props) => {
    const allChemicals = [...];

    const allBOMs = [...];

    const makeRandomStr = (length) => {...};

    const getRandomChemicals = () => {};

    const getRandomBOMs = () => {..};

    const getRandomIntInclusive = (min, max) => {...};

    const randomDate = (start, end, startHour, endHour) => {...};

    const quotes = [...];

    const getRandomComments = () => {..};

    const getBatchNumbers = () => {...};

    const [context, setContext] = useState(null);
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState(null);
    const [filteredOrders, setFilteredOrders] = useState(null);
    const [pendingOrderIDs, setPendingOrderIDs] = useState(null);
    const [activeOrder, setActiveOrder] = useState(0);
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);
    const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('Title');
    const [lineType, setLineType] = useState('Type');
    const chemicals = useState(allChemicals);
    const BOMs = useState(allBOMs);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPendingOrders = () => {
            const ordersURL = 'http://localhost:3001/orders';
            return fetch(ordersURL, {
                cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer' // no-referrer, *client
            });
        };

        fetchPendingOrders()
            .then((result) => {
                return result.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                const tempOrders = data.map((el, index) => {
                    return {
                        id: index,
                        .....
                    };
                });

                setOrders(tempOrders);
                setFilteredOrders(tempOrders);
                const pendingOrderIDVals = tempOrders.map(function(val) {
                    return val.id;
                });
                setPendingOrderIDs(pendingOrderIDVals);

                const contextValue = {
                    orders,
                    setOrders,
                    filteredOrders,
                    setFilteredOrders,
                    pendingOrderIDs,
                    setPendingOrderIDs,
                    columns,
                    setColumns,
                    showDetails,
                    setShowDetails,
                    activeOrder,
                    setActiveOrder,
                    title,
                    setTitle,
                    lineType,
                    setLineType,
                    chemicals,
                    BOMs
                };
                setContext(contextValue);

                console.log(contextValue);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }, []);



    return (
        <ScheduleContext.Provider value={context}>
            {props.children}
        </ScheduleContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

That error `TypeError: _useContext is null` is happening in a functional component in a file that reads in the context file.  These are the two relevant lines(This is the beginning of the SchedulePage.js where the error is happening):

```
import { ScheduleContext } from '../../schedule-context-new';

const Schedule = () => {
const {
        showDetails,
        orders,
        setOrders,
        activeOrder,
        columns,
        setColumns,
        title,
        pendingOrderIDs,
        filteredOrders,
        setTitle,
        lineType,
        setLineType
    } = useContext(ScheduleContext);
....
```

I'm also using the ScheduleProvider in my app.js if that makes a difference:

```
import { ScheduleProvider2 } from './schedule-context-new';
import Schedule from './components/home/SchedulePage';
import './App.scss';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <ScheduleProvider2>
            <div className={'App'}>
                <Schedule />
            </div>
        </ScheduleProvider2>
    );
};
```

**Update:**
Per the example link, I tried changing the end of my context file to this and now it is complaining about `Error: ScheduleProvider2(...): Nothing was returned from render.`

```
(async function() {
        const context = await fetchPendingOrders();

        return (
            <ScheduleContext.Provider value={context}>
                {props.children}
            </ScheduleContext.Provider>
        );
    })();
};
```

**Update 2** - I've figured out how to create a basic barebones replica of my app that actually produces the same error.  Once again for some reason, the useEffect code wasn't getting called until I commented out useEffect, I don't know why.
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-cookies-jzn5v

Comment: So would I wrap an IIFE function around my return at the bottom?

Comment: @jonrsharpe nope?

Comment: `useContext` can only be used inside functional react components.

Comment: Edited to show I am using useContect inside a functional react component.

Comment: @dmikester1, Can you provide a minimal, Reproducible sample in codesandbox env?

Comment: @Alex, I can try and do that tomorrow morning when I get into work.  It won't be easy, this project is a big one with a lot of parts.

Comment: @dmikester1, What's inside the `Schedule`

Comment: Aw, thanks for that tip.  I added in clarifying info for that now.

Comment: @dmikester1, I mean inside Schedule component,`const Schedule = () => {????`

Comment: Aw that is the main component that basically runs, routes, and holds all my other components.  I basically removed all the rest of the code from it, because I am not getting any errrors after the useContext line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207419/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-alex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should waite for API result

```
const Schedule = () => {
  const {
    orders,
    setOrders,
    filteredOrders,
    setFilteredOrders,
    pendingOrderIDs,
    setPendingOrderIDs
  } = useContext(ScheduleContext) ||[];
```

Or use `useEffect`

```
const data = useContext(ScheduleContext);

useEffect(() => {
  // Do you calculation here when ScheduleContext is ready
}, [data])
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-glade-cclgx)